# How can I access the fields of a returned tuple in Scala.js when using full optimization?

Tags: javascript, return, tuples, scala.js

The signature of the Scala function is.

scala:

```
@JSExportTopLevel("makeUciMovesScala")
  def makeUciMovesScala(
    variantKeyOptJs: js.UndefOr[String],
    fenOptJs: js.UndefOr[String],
    ucisJs: js.UndefOr[js.Array[String]]
  ):(
    js.UndefOr[String],
    js.Array[String],
    js.Array[String]
   )
```

When I look at the result, without optimization I get a dictionary with sensible names for tuple elements ( like `T3__f__1`, which stands for tuple 3, first element ).

However, with optimization, I get optimized out random tuple element names, like `N1`, `lj`, `mj`.

Currently, I use this hack that can handle both the unoptimized and optimized code.

javascript:

```
let fen = result.T3__f__1 || result.Nl
let legalMovesUcis = result.T3__f__2 || result.lj
let sanMoves = result.T3__f__3 || result.mj
```

However, I fear that these random names are not stable and can change when the code changes.

So how to safely decode a tuple returned from Scala.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot decode a Scala tuple returned from Scala.js in JavaScript code. Instead, you can return a `js.Tuple3` from Scala.js, which JavaScript will be able to naturally work with:

```scala
@JSExportTopLevel("makeUciMovesScala")
def makeUciMovesScala(
  variantKeyOptJs: js.UndefOr[String],
  fenOptJs: js.UndefOr[String],
  ucisJs: js.UndefOr[js.Array[String]]
): js.Tuple3[js.UndefOr[String], js.Array[String], js.Array[String]] = ...
```

```js
let fen = result[0];
let legalMovesUcis = result[1];
let sanMoves = result[2];
```

or, if you can use array destructuring in your JavaScript:

```js
let [fen, legalMovesUcis, sanMoves] = result;
```

The above generally applies to all Scala classes, with the exception of some primitive data types. You will always need to give to JavaScript something that it can understand. It can be JavaScript types, as above, or instances of Scala classes that offer `@JSExport`ed members.

Comment: I wonder why the compiler allows returning anything other than proper js return value. This should have been a compiler error which possibly would have made me discover that I need js.Tuple3.